# Java: Finding the shortest word in a string and printing it out

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I'm a novice with Java. I took a class in C, so I'm trying to get myself out of that mode of thinking. The program I'm writing has a section in which the user enters an integer, *n*, and then *n* number of words afterwards. This section then searches through those words and finds the shortest one, then returns it to the user. For instance, an input might be:

> **INPUT:** 4 JAVA PROGRAMMING IS FUN
>
> **OUTPUT:** IS

The code I have currently seems to return the wrong word. In this instance, it returns "PROGRAMMING", when it should return "IS". I thought maybe you all could point me in the right direction.

```
int numwords = scan.nextInt();
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();
    String shortestword = new String();
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numwords; i++){
        if (shortestword.length() < words[i].length()){
            shortestword = words[i];
    
        }
    }
    System.out.printf(shortestword);
```

To give you an idea of what I was trying to do, I was attempting to enter the words into a string, "sentence," then break that string up into individual words in an array, "words[]," then run a for loop to compare the strings to each other by comparing the lengths to the entries in the array. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, but your comparison to detect the shortest word is reversed. It should be:

```
if (words[i].length() < shortestword.length()) {
```

That is, if your current word's length is less than the length of your previous shortest word, overwrite it.

Also, instead of starting with an empty `String`, start with the *first* word, i.e., `words[0]`. Otherwise, the empty string will always be shorter than any string in your array:

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
String shortestword = words[0];
for (int i = 1; i < numwords; i++) { // start with 1, because you already have words[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel embarrassed about my if statement being reversed. Unfortunately though, after I made those changes, my program returns nothing, and instead just terminates.

Comment: Found that words[0] actually needed to be words[1]. Thanks for the step in the right direction!

Comment: @Batteries: You're welcome, don't be embarassed, it can happen, especially if you are just starting :-). Yes, that's because you have an extra whitespace in your string, between the number `4` and the first string `JAVA`, thus you end with up with an array of 5 words instead of 4. You can skip this whitespace using `scan.skip(" ");` right after `scan.nextInt()`. Then, you can use words[0].

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is wrong. This should work.

```
int numwords = scan.nextInt();
    String sentence = scan.nextLine();
    String shortestword = new String();
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numwords; i++){
        if (shortestword.length() > words[i].length()){
            shortestword = words[i];

        }
    }
    System.out.printf(shortestword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that makes use of Java 8's [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description):

```
String sentence = "PROGRAMMING IS FUN";
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));

String shortestWord = words.stream().min(
                                     Comparator.comparing(
                                     word -> word.length()))
                                    .get();

System.out.println(shortestWord);
```

You can also sort more complex objects by any of their attribute: If you have a couple of `Person`s and you wanted to sort them by their `lastName`, shortest first, the code becomes:

```
Person personWithShortestName = persons.stream().min(
                                                 Comparator.comparing(
                                                 person -> person.lastName.length()))
                                                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8** has made it simpler. Convert your `String` array to a list and use `sorted()` to compare and sort your list in ascending order. Finally, use `findFirst()` to get the first value of your list (which is shortest after sorting).

have a look,

```
String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "name", "is", "Bob"};
String shortest = Arrays.asList(words).stream()
      .sorted((e2, e1) -> e1.length() > e2.length() ? -1 : 1)
      .findFirst().get();

System.out.println(shortest);
```