# finding the shortest word in an array of strings java

Tags: java, debugging

im trying to write a code to take in a group of words, and return the smallest word in character length. pretty simple, for some reason its returning 'bye' when there is a shorter word in there such as 'no'.

```
public class function2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String [] SA = {"hello", "goodbye", "jack", "bye", "yes", "no", "yoo"};
        smallest(SA);
        System.out.println("The shortest word is " + smallest(SA));
    }

    public static String smallest(String SA[]) {
        String first = SA[0];
        for (int i = 1 ; i < SA.length ; i++) {
            if ((SA[i].compareTo(first)) < 0) {
                first = SA[i];
            } // if
        } // for
        return first;
    }// smallest
}// lab1b
```

Comment: shouldnt have left that in there, sorry lol.

Comment: it compiles, i just cant get the correct return im looking for @Pshemo

Comment: Shouldn't you have a check for the string length in there somewhere since that is what you are comparing? Something like `if (SA[i].length() < first.length())`.

Comment: if((SA[i].compareTo(first))<0)

the compareto function returns a negative number if the string at index i is smaller than the word that first is = to.

Comment: @BenjiWeiss That's not what `compareTo` does. It checks for alphabetical order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Finding the shortest word in a string and printing it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326899/java-finding-the-shortest-word-in-a-string-and-printing-it-out)

Answer (score 9):

`compareTo` doesn't compare length of Strings, but their alphabetic order.

You should change your condition to `if (SA[i].length()<first.length())`.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8,  you create a `Comparator` that will check the length of string which would make the array ascending, convert that list in a stream, and use `sorted` to sort the array, eventually, use `findFirst` to return the first element and `get()` to convert it into a `String`.

```
String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "aadsads", "adssadsadads", "aaa"};
String shortest = Arrays.asList(words).stream()
        .sorted((e2, e1) -> e1.length() > e2.length() ? -1 : 1)
        .findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Shortest algorithm with Java 8+ using elegant Comparator.comparing method.

```
final String shortest = List.of("hello", "yes", "no")
                          .stream()
                          .min(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
                          .get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method is close, but your variable names are a bit difficult to read to start you only need to call your method once to print the shortest name (calling it twice searches twice, and discards the first result),

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] SA = { "hello", "goodbye", "jack", "bye", "yes", "no", "yoo" };
    System.out.println("The shortest word is " + smallest(SA));
}
```

Next, it's usually a good idea to test that your input is valid (not `null` and at least one element). You should also decide how you want to handle those cases, I chose to `return "";` below. Finally, you need to check `length()` the String(s) to get the shortest word. Something like,

```
public static String smallest(String words[]) {
    if (words == null || words.length < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    String smallest = words[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() < smallest.length()) {
            smallest = words[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}// smallest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words =
            {"hello", "goodbye", "jack", "bye", "yes", "no", "yoo"};
        System.out.println(shortestWord(words));
    }

    static String shortestWord(String[] words) {
        return asList(words).stream().min(compareBy(String::length)).get();
    }

    static <A, B extends Comparable<B>> Comparator<A> compareBy(
            Function<A, B> f) {
        return (A x, A y) -> f.apply(x).compareTo(f.apply(y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are trying to do with the method compareTo(), but if you want to keep find the length of a string you use the length() method.

```
public class function 2
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] SA = {"hello" , "goodbye"  , "jack" , "bye" , "yes" , "no" , "yoo"};

        System.out.println("The shortest word is " + smallest(SA));
    }

    public static String smallest(String SA[]) {
        //Keep track of the shortest word by index and length
        int index = 0, minLength = SA[0].length();
        for (int i = 1; i < SA.length; i++){
            //if the next string is smaller in length then we save that index and length in our variables
            if(SA[i].length() < minLength){
                index = i;
                minLength = SA[i].length();  
            }           
        }
        //returns the smallest word
        return SA[index];
    }

}
```