# Shortest word length when user inputs two words of choice

Tags: java

I just needed help with a particular part that I cannot seem to figure out. The object is to get the user to input two words and have the program output which one is the shortest.

For example:

Enter first word: `Island`

Enter the second Word: `Fire`

The shortest length is: `4`

With the shortest word being `Fire` just as an example

The hardest part for me, as I am really just a beginner in java is figuring out how to allow the system to read both inputs and tell which one is the shortest. I need to be able to do this with the String and Math class.

The last lines of code is just me trying to figure things out, with no luck

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortestWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // User inputs first word
        System.out.print("Enter your first word: ");
        String word1 = scan.next();

        // User inputs second word
        System.out.print("Enter your second word: ");
        String word2 = scan.next();

        // Accounts for both words to figure out which is the shortest    
        bWords = Math.min(word1, word2);
        System.out.println("THC: " + bWords.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: `bWords = Math.min( word1, word2 );` doesn't really make sense. `Math.min` compares numbers, not Strings. I can't say more without doing your homework for you, aside form the fact that you probably don't even need to use it. Simple comparison operators should be enough.

Comment: Okay, start with [`Math.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-), it requires a numeric value, not a `String`, so your question boils down to needing to figure out how you can get the number of characters from the `String` as numeric value. This should lead you to having a look at [the JavaDocs for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see if you can find a suitable method for your needs.  In fact, you've already used it in. your code

Comment: Also, instead of `scan.next ( )` I might recommend `scan.nextLine()` as it reduces the risk of the user entering "Hello there" and the second scan been skipped

Comment: You don't even have to use `Math.min`, just compare `word1.length()` and `word2.length()` and print the smaller value.

Comment: You want your code to do certains things **if** a condition holds, and do something **else** if the condition does not hold. Therefore, you need some kind of *control flow* primitives in your code. Can you come up with suitable control flow construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `length` of your two `String`(s) by getting the `length()`

```
// User inputs first word
System.out.print("Enter your first word: ");
String word1 = scan.next();

// User inputs second word
System.out.print("Enter your second word: ");
String word2 = scan.next();
if (word1.length() < word2.length()) {
    System.out.printf("%s is shorter than %s%n", word1, word2);
} else if (word1.length() > word2.length()) {
    System.out.printf("%s is longer than %s%n", word1, word2);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%s is the same length as %s%n", word1, word2);
}
```

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and **answer** homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: spot on @Pshemo. The asker here needs to be led to the correct answer, not be be fed with it

Comment: Passive aggressive much?

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int)), which  clearly shows that the parameters must be numeric:

```
public static int min(int a, int b)
```

The JavaDoc also says that `Math#min` returns a a numeric value, thus `bWords = Math.min(word1, word2)` makes no sense.

With this  knowledge, you can conclude that `bWords` should be an integer and thus `String#length` should not be called  on `bWords`, but rather a different variable. After  that, the rest should be easier.

If you are not familiar with JavaDocs, there is even easier solution. Try researching it. Many people have [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326899/java-finding-the-shortest-word-in-a-string-and-printing-it-out) these questions. You just need to [look for it](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS546US546&ei=i-V0WuuKGYfbjwTviqWwBA&q=java+shortest+of+two+strings&oq=java+short&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0l2j0i67k1j0l6.7757.8632.0.9297.6.6.0.0.0.0.126.601.2j4.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.600...0i20i263k1.0.K82kaNHBE48). That is why that  is why you are [**required** to research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Comment: maybe use "easier". We all started thinking that the swap algorithm was a little hard to figure out